# Possible null reference assignment warning seems bogus to me

Tags: c#, .net-5, nullable, nullable-reference-types

The following code is giving me a warning but I don't understand why.

```
client.Host = Settings.Host;
```

> warning CS8601: Possible null reference assignment.

Both `client` and `Settings` are not null here. And both `client.Host` and `Settings.Host` are of type `string?`.

Therefore, while it could be a possible null reference assignment, it shouldn't matter because the target variable allows null.

[image: client.Host may be null]

[image: Settings.Host may be null]

Comment: While `SmtpClient.Host` is indeed a nullable string, using the setter to set it to null will throw an `ArgumentNullException`. See the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs). The compiler is probably just cleverly inferring that (it has the `DisallowNull` attribute).

Comment: @sellotape: This is a very specific warning, and I do not believe it is considering the fact that the setter could throw an exception. However, the fact that the property is marked with `[DisallowNull]` is almost certainly the issue. The compiler see this attribute and warns of potential null values even though the data type allows it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice the [DisallowNull](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/331cfe33e187a6234aa2c2447f91793f154bd322/src/libraries/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs#L157) attribute on the `Host` property declaration.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.disallownullattribute?view=net-5.0)

> Specifies that null is disallowed as an input even if the
> corresponding type allows it.

```
[DisallowNull]
public string? Host
```

Since it is declared in the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace, Visual Studios code analyzer will take this into account.

Comment: It's too bad there's no way to see this without seeing the source code. In fact, Intellisense specifically says it can be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AllowNullAttribute class which:

> Specifies that null is allowed as an input even if the corresponding type disallows it.

for example:

```
[AllowNullAttribute]
public string Host
```

This way you wont get those annoying warnings!

Answer (score -3):

string? is already declared, intellisence will definitly take it into nullable value on some cases.